# Equivalent of Wavefront align in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, operation, wavefront-telegraf

I am trying to move existing dashboards from Wavefront to Prometheus. The metric counter reset every 1 min by the library that pushes the metrics to Wavefront.

Wavefront query:

```
align(${ds_unit}, sum, sum(ts(metricName_counter, cluster="${cluster_name}" and customer="${customer_name}"), customer))
```

ds_unit = 1 min. Prometheus query (to replicate the reset after every min in Wavefront I am using increase function):

```
sum by (customer) (increase(metricName_counter [1m]))
```

Wavefront sums it up by customer and then buckets it using align and sums again whatever value falls in the bucket. I am not sure if we have something similar in Prometheus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [subquery](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) to perform a secondary range aggregation

`sum_over_time(sum by (customer) (increase(metricName_counter[1m]))[1m:1m])`

From the link:

> `<instant_query> '[' <range> ':' [ <resolution> ] ']' [ offset <duration> ]`
>
> - `<instant_query>` is equivalent to `query` field in `/query_range` API.
> - `<range>` and `offset <duration>` is similar to a range selector.
> - `<resolution>` is optional, which is equivalent to `step` in `/query_range` API

Setting `offset` and `duration` to the same value emulates what wavefront's `align` function does, which is accumulate all the points in time bucket and apply an aggregation.